# Use jQuery to change css of text with select option - how to combine multiple functions

Tags: jquery

This is my first time using jQuery and I am pleased to get my first attempt working.
With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024516/div-css-change-when-select-option-is-selected-with-jquery) I managed to achieve what I wanted to do, but I can't help feeling that there is a much neater way of doing this but cannot work out how.

Basically I have a page containing dropdowns that change a price depending on the service level wanted.
When the select options are changed the color of the price also changes.
These prices come from a db so I have put a basic version here where the price doesn't change but the text color does.

The id of each dropdown increments like this - optn0x0, optn1x0 etc

and the div id of the price increments like this pricediv0, pricediv1 etc

What I would like to do is combine the jQuery code into one function as there are 13 dropdowns so it will be a lot of code the way I have done it.

Here is the code

```
<style>
.saver{color:red;}
.express{color:black;}
.expressplus{color:blue;}
</style>

<html>

<select class="prodoption" name="optn0" id="optn0x0"><option value="68">Saver</option>
<option value="69" selected="selected">Express</option>
<option value="70">ExpressPlus</option>
</select>

<td class="cobll cpdll"><div class="prod3price"><span class="price" id="pricediv0">74.00</span></div></td>

<select class="prodoption" name="optn0" id="optn1x0"><option value="68">Saver</option>
<option value="69" selected="selected">Express</option>
<option value="70">ExpressPlus</option>
</select>

<td class="cobll cpdll"><div class="prod3price"><span class="price" id="pricediv1">74.00</span></div></td>
</html>
```

and here is the jQuery

```
$('select[id^=optn0x0]').change(function(){

$('#pricediv0').removeClass('saver express expressplus').addClass(
    $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase()
);
})
.change();

$('select[id^=optn1x0]').change(function(){

$('#pricediv1').removeClass('saver express expressplus').addClass(
    $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase()
);
})
.change();
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

---

Hi,

Thank you all for your answers on this

I now have two working solutions:

```
$('select[id^="optn"]').change(function(){
var ind = $(this).attr('id').replace('optn', '')
var cls = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
$('#pricediv' + parseInt(ind) ).removeAttr('class').addClass(cls)
})
.change();
```

and

```
$('select[id^="optn"]').change(function(){
var ind = $(this).attr('id').replace('optn', '')
$('#pricediv' + parseInt(ind) ).removeClass('saver express expressplus').addClass(
   $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase()
)
})
.change();
```

Would anyone be able to offer any guidance as to which one is best and therefore which one I should use as I am new to jQuery and I am trying to understand what does what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('select[id^="optn"]').change(function(){
    var ind = $(this).attr('id').replace('optn', '')
    var cls = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
    $('#pricediv' + parseInt(ind) ).removeAttr('class').addClass(cls)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63MQu/10/

Comment: `$("#elem").change()` is equivalent to `$("#elem").trigger("change")`. There is no harm in triggering the event that way.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be working. Also, you're missing a semi-colon

Comment: @Joey "you're missing a semi-colon" where?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answers on this. I now have two working examples (please see edit in my original question) and I was wondering which one is best suited to my task. I would like to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @quadrant Hi, you are welcome, I'd recommend this which works with every number optn1 to optn22222, however there is no specific difference between the two. in fiddle i have alerted some of the variable values to show how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$('select[id^="optn"]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var n = $this.attr('id').charAt($this.attr('id').length-3);
    var p = $('#pricediv' + n);
    p.removeClass('saver express expressplus').addClass(
       $this.find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase()
    )
})​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qkQ8/4/)

The drawback is that you are limited to single characters. I suggest having the price tag share an attribute with the corresponding select tag. Like the name, for instance (which should be unique to begin with).

Also `td`'s shouldn't be used outside of a table. Just use `div` or `span`